# Разное время выполнения в простейшей симуляции

Tags: c++, sfml

Написал простой алгоритм который должен реагировать на правую стрелку на клавиатуре, и задавать телу ускорение, когда отпускаю кнопку тело должно двигаться с постоянной скоростью, опять нажимаю, скорость должна расти. Всё работает, но очень плохо, после того, как отпускаю стрелку скорость тела значительно возрастаёт, так же после нажатия кнопки скорость значительно падает, это если смотреть по по окну на анимацию, если в консоли вывести обе скорости, то то они правильные. Пытался исправить через замер времени выполнения цикла когда кнопка нажата, и перед циклом делал sf::sleep(sf::seconds(время)), но это не помогает. Пытался делать привязку ко времени через clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();, но там такая же проблема. Мучаюсь уже 2 дня с этим. Как исправить данную проблему ?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Vikno");   // 1280 пикселей = 128 метров
    double a = 20, V = 0, t = 0, t1 = 0, x = 0, x1 = 0, begX = 0, V_global = 0;
    bool begXreset = 0, begXreset1 = 0, rightkeypressed = 0;
    double fps = 120;
    window.setFramerateLimit(fps);

    begX = begX * 10;
    sf::CircleShape kulka1(20, 30);
    kulka1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    kulka1.setPosition(begX, 580);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        if (begXreset1) begX = x1;
        sf::Event event;
        window.pollEvent(event);
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape)) window.close();
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
            t += 1 / fps;
            V = V_global + t * a;
            x = ((V * t) / 2) * 10 + begX;
            kulka1.setPosition(x, 580);
            begXreset = 1;
            rightkeypressed = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            rightkeypressed = 0;
            t = 0;
            begX = x;
            V_global = V;
        }


        if (rightkeypressed == 0)
        {
            t1 += 1 / fps;
            x1 = V_global * t1 * 10 + begX;
            kulka1.setPosition(x1, 580);
            begXreset1 = 1;
        }
        else t1 = 0;

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.draw(kulka1);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: это случаем не дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210791/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-sfml ?

Comment: я не смог зайти в тот аккаунт чтобы обновить код поэтому написал новый вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вот универсальный код:

```cpp
int main()
{
    //...
    float dt = clock.restart().asSeconds();// получаем время с предыдущего кадра
    float speed = 10.0f; // начальная скорость
    float a = 20.0f; // ускорение
    sf::Vector2f dir(1.0f, 0.0f); // можно использовать единичный вектор задающий направление
    sf::Vector2f pos(100.0f, 100.0f); // начальная позиция

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
    {
        speed += a * dt; // увеличиваем скорость
    }
    
    pos += dir * speed * dt; // двигаем тело
    //...
}
```

Вывод в консоль (std::cout) очень сильно влияет на частоту кадров, рекомендуется [выводить данные на окно sfml](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-text.php).